# How to change the help command in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have recently found the following screenshot and I was wondering how it is possible to get this behavior using discord.py in my discord bot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking at is a [**customized discord-like**](https://github.com/Xenon-Bot/Discord-chat-replica) chat from [**Xenon**](https://xenon.bot/). This chat allows you to Discord-like chat section, but emulates the behaviour of **Discord**. Xenon is open source, so just check their [repositories](https://github.com/Xenon-Bot) if you want to do the same as they do.

If you want to customize the **help** command of your bot, which all bots have, you can do it with the recent changes of discord.py-rewrite. Toa chieve what you want you will need to subclass **HelpCommand** or **MinimalHelpCommand**, then pass it to `bot.help_command`.

The following code shows the standard way of subclassing MinimalHelpCommand:

```
class MyHelpCommand(commands.MinimalHelpCommand):
    def get_command_signature(self, command):
        return '{0.clean_prefix}{1.qualified_name} {1.signature}'.format(self, command)

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self._original_help_command = bot.help_command
        bot.help_command = MyHelpCommand()
        bot.help_command.cog = self

    def cog_unload(self):
        self.bot.help_command = self._original_help_command
```

For more info, discord.py documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#help-commands